# L’uso della “m” prima delle lettere “p” e "b"

Tags: orthography

La regola grammaticale è chiara: prima delle consonanti labiali “b” e “p” va sempre la lettera “m“.

Quindi si dice “bambino” e non “banbino”.

“Compleanno” e non “conpleanno".

Qual è l'origine di questa regola? A livello di pronuncia non mi sembra che la lettera 'n' sia più difficile da pronunciare rispetto alla 'm' nel contesto di cui sopra.

Comment: @Charo: Scusa la pedanteria: quando dici “con alcuna eccezione” intendi “con qualche eccezione”? Lo chiedo perché visto che “alcuno” si usa anche in frasi negative («Non c'è alcun motivo per...»), anche se non ha da solo un significato negativo, può venire il dubbio.

Comment: Assimilazione della nasale con la labiale (non sono sicuro che il termine sia del tutto giusto). Credo che sia un fenomeno tipico dell'italiano “centrale” (toscano, romano). In veneto il fenomeno non c'è e si dice tranquillamente *banbin*. Non era raro trovare “errori” ortografici come *conpleanno* negli scritti dei banbini `;-)` di queste parti.

Comment: Questa stessa regola esiste anche in spagnolo ([http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/m_%28letra%29](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/m_%28letra%29)) e in catalano (con qualche eccezione).

Comment: Sì, @DaG, voglio dire "con qualche eccezione". Ho corretto il mio commento.

Comment: Le eccezioni ci sono sempre.
Anche in questo caso ad esempio i nomi di luoghi non rispettano la regola.
E non possiamo certo modificare Istanbul in "Istambul"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si tratta di una regola di derivazione fonetica/glottologica, in parole povere.
Se si pronuncia un suono nasale seguito immediatamente da un suono labiale senza interruzione di aria e in assenza di vocale fra i due suoni – ad esempio, *np*, *nb*, *mp*, *mb* – succede che il movimento di avvicinamento delle labbra in seguito al suono nasale dà come risultato la naturale formazione del suono *m*.

La pronuncia veneta che cita l'utente egreg non rispetta quanto sopra, poiché in effetti avviene una interruzione (seppur minima e quasi impercettibile).

Comment: Allora e' il fatto che io sia Veneto che non mi fa percepire  questa differenza. Grazie, molto interessante.

Comment: È interessante quello che dici sulla interruzione o non interruzione di aria tra i suoni ***n*** o ***m*** e ***p*** o ***b***. Come ho già detto, lo stesso fenomeno avviene in catalano e in spagnolo. In catalano, le solite eccezioni a questa regola sono le parole composte di "ben" (bene) come "benplantada", "benparlat", "benpensat"... A pensarci bene, c'è una piccola interruzione dopo "ben" nella pronuncia di tali parole che non c'è, per esempio, nella pronuncia di "company" (compagno) o di "ample" (ampio).

Answer (score 1):

Sono d'accordissimo con quanto spiegato da "in Cina" nell'altra risposta. Aggiungo soltanto che non mi sembra assolutamente una regola specifica dell'italiano.

Per esempio, in inglese non esistono parole di uso comune che contengano *-np-* se non quelle che sono la combinazione di due parole e quindi si pronunciano separate (oppure... si pronunciano con *-mp-*). L'unica che ho trovato usando un metadizionario online è *enplane*: verificatelo voi stessi in questa [lista di parole in inglese di uso comune che contengono *-np-*](http://www.onelook.com/?w=*np*&loc=scworef&scwo=1&sswo=1&ls=a). Per confronto ecco invece una [lista di parole in inglese di uso comune che contengono *-mp-*](http://www.onelook.com/?w=*mp*&loc=scworef&scwo=1&sswo=1&ls=a): sono tantissime.

Risultati del tutto analoghi si trovano confrontando [*-nb-*](http://www.onelook.com/?w=*nb*&loc=scworef&scwo=1&sswo=1&ls=a) con [*-mb-*](http://www.onelook.com/?w=*mb*&loc=scworef&scwo=1&sswo=1&ls=a).

Comment: Per dare a “in Cina” quel che è di “in Cina”, io ho solo limato qualche cosa della punteggiatura: la risposta è sua.

Comment: Ops, hai ragione. Correggo.

Comment: Hai ragione, @Mauro. Come ho già detto, anche in catalano e in spagnolo è lo stesso.